# What can be used instead of Datatable in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a SQL query that returns a Datatable:

```
var routesTable = _dbhelper.Select("SELECT [RouteId],[UserId],[SourceName],[CreationTime] FROM [Routes] WHERE UserId=@UserId AND RouteId=@RouteId", inputParams);
```

and then we can work with Datatable object of  *routesTable*

```
if (routesTable.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                result = new Route(routeId)
                {
                    Name = (string)routesTable.Rows[0]["SourceName"],
                    Time = routesTable.Rows[0]["CreationTime"] is DBNull ? new DateTime() : Convert.ToDateTime(routesTable.Rows[0]["CreationTime"])
                };

                result.TrackPoints = GetTrackPointsForRoute(routeId);
            }
```

I want to change this code to linq but I don't know how can I simulate Datatable in LINQ ,I wrote this part:

```
Route result = null;
            aspnetdbDataContext aspdb = new aspnetdbDataContext();
            var Result = from r in aspdb.RouteLinqs
                           where r.UserId == userId && r.RouteId==routeId
                           select r;


    ....
```

but I don't know how can I change this part:

```
if (routesTable.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                result = new Route(routeId)
                {
                    Name = (string)routesTable.Rows[0]["SourceName"],
                     Time = routesTable.Rows[0]["CreationTime"] is DBNull ? new DateTime() : Convert.ToDateTime(routesTable.Rows[0]["CreationTime"])
                };
```

would you please tell me how can I do this?

**EDIT**
here you can see the whole block of code in original

```
public Route GetById(int routeId, Guid userId)
        {
            Route result = null;
            var inputParams = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                  {
                                      {"UserId", userId},
                                      {"RouteId", routeId}
                                  };

            var routesTable = _dbhelper.Select("SELECT [RouteId],[UserId],[SourceName],[CreationTime] FROM [Routes] WHERE UserId=@UserId AND RouteId=@RouteId", inputParams);

            if (routesTable.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                result = new Route(routeId)
                {
                    Name = (string)routesTable.Rows[0]["SourceName"],
                    Time = routesTable.Rows[0]["CreationTime"] is DBNull ? new DateTime() : Convert.ToDateTime(routesTable.Rows[0]["CreationTime"])
                };

                result.TrackPoints = GetTrackPointsForRoute(routeId);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

SELECT Function:

```
public DataTable Select(string query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();

            using (_command = new SqlCommand(query, _connnection))
            {
                InitializeParametersAndConnection(parameters);

                using (_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_command))
                {
                    _adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

and the GetTrackPointsForRoute

```
private List<TrackPoint> GetTrackPointsForRoute(int routeId)
        {
            aspnetdbDataContext aspdb = new aspnetdbDataContext();
            var result = new List<TrackPoint>();
            var trackPointsTable = from t in aspdb.TrackPointlinqs
                                   where t.RouteFK == routeId
                                   select t;
            foreach (var trackPointRow in trackPointsTable)
            {
                var trackPoint = new TrackPoint
                {
                    Id = (int)trackPointRow.TrackPointId,
                    Elevation = Convert.ToSingle(trackPointRow.Elevation),
                    Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(trackPointRow.Latitude),
                    Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(trackPointRow.Longitude),
                    Time = trackPointRow.TrackTime is DBNull ? new DateTime() : (DateTime)trackPointRow.TrackTime
                };
                result.Add(trackPoint);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: How do you know that your original code was a sensible way to solve the problem in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also `var Result =` is misleading because that line doesn't construct the result. It constructs a query. Also, it's a bad practice to use two variables that only differ in case (`result` and `Result`).

Comment: I want to change my code into LINQ ,I also edited my post

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL or LINQ to entity framework?

Comment: Sorry I'm a little bit new in this field I want only change SQL command with LINQ ,I think LINQ to SQL

Comment: GetTrackPointsForRoute can also be simplified by using Select(...).ToList(). Also, you could probably get both the route and the points with a single select by using a join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var firstRoute = aspdb.RouteLinqs
    .Where(r => r.UserId == userId && r.RouteId == routeId)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (firstRoute == null)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return new Route(routeId)
    {
        Name = first.SourceName,
        Time = first.CreationTime ?? new DateTime(),
        TrackPoints = GetTrackPointsForRoute(routeId)
    };
}
```

If this is LINQ to SQL you can simplify it further (this won't work with LINQ to Entity Framework though):

```
return aspdb.RouteLinqs
    .Where(r => r.UserId == userId && r.RouteId == routeId)
    .Select(r => new Route(routeId)
    {
        Name = r.SourceName,
        Time = r.CreationTime ?? new DateTime(),
        TrackPoints = GetTrackPointsForRoute(routeId)
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: You probably can replace `GetTrackPointsForRoute` with a join to the child table, meaning that the entire method can be done with a single call to the database, rather than one call to get the routes, and a second call to get the points. To do this you should learn about associations and joins in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Hi Mark,THNK YOU,I think you answerd me,but I want to clear my situation more :This block of code returns a Route and calculate some things for this route(I work with GPX )  also edited my post